# Speed in java why some codes run faster

Tags: java, performance, optimization, time

I was Attempting UVa problem number [10324](https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=onlinejudge&page=show_problem&problem=1265)
and I coded the following solution this gets an accepted but gives a really **bad runtime of 2.670 seconds** 
I have the following two codes
This is my code

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        // write your code here
        StringBuilder op = new StringBuilder();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String input, tmp[];
            int n, l, u, j, i = 0;
            boolean dec;
            char thi;
            while ((input = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                op.append("Case " + (++i) + ":\n");
                n = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
                while (n-- > 0) {
                    tmp = reader.readLine().split(" ");
                    l = Integer.parseInt(tmp[0]);
                    u = Integer.parseInt(tmp[1]);
                    if (l > u) {
                        l ^= u;
                        u ^= l;
                        l ^= u;
                    }
                    //System.out.println(l + "|" + u);
                    dec = true;
                    thi = input.charAt(l++);
                    for (; l <= u; l++) {
                        if (thi != input.charAt(l)||(thi != input.charAt(u--))) {
                            dec = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    op.append((dec ? "Yes\n" : "No\n"));
                }
            }
            System.out.print(op.toString());
            return;

    }
}
```

and the other code is one I found off the [Mr Gorgon's Solution](http://kapelosh.blogspot.in/2013/10/10324-zeros-and-ones-java.html)
This has a **runtime of 0.84 seconds**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
    int testCase = 1;
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append("Case ").append(testCase).append(":\n");
        testCase++;
        int noOfCases = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        for (int j = 0; j < noOfCases; j++) {
            String[] str = br.readLine().split(" ");
            int val1 = Integer.parseInt(str[0]);
            int val2 = Integer.parseInt(str[1]);
            if (val1 > val2) {
                val1 ^= val2;
                val2 ^= val1;
                val1 ^= val2;
            }
            boolean isValid = true;
            if (val1 != val2) {
                for (int i = val1; i < val2; i++) {
                    if (line.charAt(i) != line.charAt(i + 1)) {
                        isValid = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (isValid)
                sb.append("Yes\n");
            else
                sb.append("No\n");
        }
    }
    System.out.print(sb);
}
```

I found it extremely hard to understand as to why this code runs so much faster when all the tasks are essentially same.and my code has lesser declarations than Gorgons code

Comment: declarations does not really add much performance overhead in fact (and I don't see you are really have any declaration lesser...)

Comment: I created some test cases with several really long strings and lots of shorter ones and ran the two versions locally (windows and linux, jdk8), and your version is about 2 times faster. It would be interesting to know their (UVa's) actual test cases and the java runtime they are using.

Answer (score 2):

- `op.append("Case " + (++i) + ":\n");`

This negates the benefits of StringBuilder

- `if (val1 != val2) {`  In the second version shortcuts the looping

Comment: Your second point is not valid. The OP's loop condition will also not go into the loop if the two values are the same.

Comment: Nope tried making the changes still getting the same time

Answer (score 2):

its the

```
input.charAt(l)!=input.charAt(l+1)
```

line which helps to speed up the program i think it has to do with caching

I researched and found something called **[JCS](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jcs/)**
which probably allows their apache server to ache the memory data and helps in faster access

Comment: JCS is irrelevant to this, but you are correct that this line is what makes the code run substantially faster compared to your version

Answer (score -1):

Below piece of code is missing in your solution. You are looping blindly where as if condition limits looping.

```
if (val1 != val2) {
                                    }
            }
```